# Preparing my own dataset in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi i want to know how to prepare my own dataset in Tensorflow
I have thousands of images in .PNG format and labels are stored in a text file with .TXT format (each label separated with a new line). How i can prepare them for training in tensorflow?
PNG files names are like 1.png, 2.png, 3.png and so on... TXT file contains labels separated by new lines (Each line contains a single label)
It will be highly appreciated if some one can give some specific example.

Answer (score -1):

Usually in tensorflow you write a small python program that reads input,
in whatever format, converts to int or float arrays and feeds to the
tensorflow graph via placeholders.

There is an example in MNIST tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html

The way they read data is

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

I never worked with images so I don't know if the use some standard file
format and whether there are tools to generate data in that format.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but since i am new, it is really hard for me to understand this from the above mentioned tutorial. It will be highly appreciated If someone can give specific examples of reading png and txt files.